# How to attach files to Mantis Connect mc_issue_add

Tags: c#, mantis

Im wondering if I can attach files using filename on MantisConnect. I've tried the ff without luck.

```
var mc = new MantisBt.Service.Client.MantisBt.Api.MantisConnect();
IssueData iIssue = new IssueData() {
    //some other properties here...
    attachments = new AttachmentData[] { 
                          filename = "path-to-my-attachment",
                          date_submitted = DateTime.Now 
                  }
};
string issueID = mc.mc_issue_add(MyUserID, MyPassword, iIssue);
```

The issue was posted in Mantis but the attachment is not added. I'm sure that the `"path-to-my-attachment"` exists: `(FileInfo.Exists == true)`

I have also tried:

```
IssueData iIssue = new IssueData();
//some other properties here
iIssue.attachments = 
//tried converting a List<AttachmentData> to array
//tried the usual AttachmentData[] method
//tried adding AttachmentData["length here"]
```

but the same thing, issue is posted, no attachments added.

***Anyone?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `mc_issue_attachment_add`, `mc_issue_add` and `mc_issue_update` don't allow adding attachments.

Comment: thanks for the answer. actually, i think the only way to add attachments is `mc_issue_attachment_add`. that is, you need to save the issue first then use the id from the response to add attachment via `mc_issue_attachment_add`. I just hoped there was a way to add attachments so that we can just call `mc_issue_add`

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that somehow, populating the attachments property of IssueData and saving the issue via `mc_issue_add` or `mc_issue_update` does not save the attachments. only way is to save the issue first, use the id then use `mc_issue_attachment_add`.

So NO. you cannot use the `attachments` property to add bulk attachments. you need to add them one-by-one using `mc_issue_attachment_add`.